# Comment traduire « trim » ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie

Plusieurs langages informatiques ont une fonction appelée `trim()`.

Pour les non-initiés, sans trop entrer dans les détails, cette fonction enlève les espaces au début et à la fin d'une chaîne de caractères.

Par exemple, si une chaîne de caractère contient les caractères suivants (sans les doubles-guillemets):

```
"  abcd     "
```

la fonction `trim()` appliquée à cette chaîne retourne (sans les doubles-guillemets) :

```
"abcd"
```

Comment peut-on traduire *trim* dans un tel contexte ?

[Google](http://translate.google.com/#pt/fr/trim) propose, *couper*, *rogner*, *tailler*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de traduction "standard" à ma connaissance.

Habituellement, mes collègues et moi utilisons le mot *trim* non traduit. Nous parlons même de *trim gauche* et *trim droit* ou encore de *trim avant* et *trim après* lorsqu'il s'agit de ne s'intéresser qu'aux espaces situés avant ou après la chaîne.

Une fois cependant, il m'a fallu traduire ce mot pour expliquer ce en quoi la fonction *trim* consiste. Je n'ai pas trouvé mieux que *suppression des espaces autour de la chaîne*.

Comment: Il n'est en effet pas traduit lorsqu'il s'agit d'évoquer la méthode informatique ; les exemples cités sont très souvent entendus dans les services où l'on programme. Il est plus facile d'expliquer par un exemple, comme Luc l'a fait dans sa question, que de trouver une formulation sans jargon.

Comment: En l'occurrence, j'avais besoin des deux : explication formelle et exemples. Je suis d'accord avec toi, l'exemple est bien souvent le plus explicite, y compris dans les docs de programmation d'ailleurs.

Comment: Que celui ou celle qui dispense des -1 ait la gentillesse de proposer quelque chose :)

Comment: Il est fort peu probable que la personne moins-disante lise votre commentaire, et cela est dommage ... pour elle ; victime de ce genre de comportement (malgré l'invitation du site à formuler un argumentaire) je range au rayon des trolls de telles provocateurs qui confondent affirmation de l'ego et confrontation d'idées, idées qui peuvent amener un **EDIT** valorisant la première réponse.

Answer (score 11):

On parle d’« [élagage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9laguer) » en matière d’arbres. Évidemment, le fait que le terme concerne à l’origine les (véritables) arbres le rend peut-être moins à propos en matière de chaînes.

Si tu penses que c’est le cas, il me semble que le terme adéquat ici serait « [rogner](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rogner) », mais ce n’est qu’un avis personnel qui n’est pas basé sur un constat d’usage. Et si l’on écoutait mes avis personnels, on considérerait que « programmeur » et « implémenter » sont d’horribles anglicismes à proscrire.

Comment: "implémenter" je comprends, mais pourquoi "programmeur" ?

Comment: L'_OQLF_ a choisi (2001) [_rognage_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871348) pour _trimming_ et il y a référence directe à la fonction `trim()`.

Comment: Problème : rogner est déjà la traduction généralement admise pour la fonction "crop" des images.

Answer (score 4):

**Détourer** ?

[Selon wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9tourer) :

> Le détourage est une opération consistant à ne retenir d'une
>   illustration qu'une partie.
>
> Il faut pour cela séparer l'objet et le fond, donc délimiter le
>   contour de l'objet.

[Sur linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/d%E9tourage.html) on trouve aussi des traductions qui vont en ce sens :

> Dans le cadre de son service clés en main pour un certain fabricant de
>   véhicules de luxe, l'entreprise fournit un dispositif de détourage
>   multi-cavités avec le programme de détourage en 5 axes de WorkNC pour
>   la finition des pièces sur les machines du client.

->

> As part of its turnkey service to one particular luxury vehicle
>   manufacturer, the company supplies multi cavity trimming fixtures and
>   the associated 5-axis WorkNC trimming program for finishing the parts
>   on the customer's own machinery.

Comment: Dans les usages habituels du mots, *détourer* est réservé aux traitements industriels : http://www.studya.com/formations_metiers/industrie/detoureur.htm ; je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans le monde informatique

Comment: Ah mais pas du tout ! Ce terme est très présent dans le monde de la retouche photo aussi, comme l'indique d'ailleurs l'article de wikipedia que j'ai cité, et tous les logiciels de traitement d'image sont équipés d'outils de "détourage" évolués : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpjCJtxOGPQ et/ou http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXlnoYsmxTU . Et la retouche photo est un traitement d'ordre artisanal... Il y aurait eut été un bouton de moinssanossage de commentaire que j'y aurais eu été moinssanogassé le vôtre !

Comment: Le monde de la photo et du traitement de l'image n'est pas concerné par celui des chaînes de caractères et de leurs manipulations : *détourer* une photo est un terme de graphiste, faire un *trim* sur une chaîne un terme de programmeur qui veut la *nettoyer* des caractères non significatifs. Deux métiers complétement différents (quoique liés à l'informatique) qui utilisent chacun un jargon adapté aux problèmes qu'ils rencontrent. *Détourer* peut aussi être employé par un peintre, *trim* non ; alors qu'un programmeur ouvrira de grands yeux si vous lui demander de détourer une chaîne.

Comment: Mais... je le sais bien que détourer n'est jamais employé en informatique ! mais la question c'est comment traduire, en informatique, ce terme, donc j'y réponds ! Je le sais bien que c'est Shlublu qui a raison en pratique (d'ailleurs je lui ai plussé), mais si quelqu'un veut quand même traduire ce terme je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne lui répondrait pas si un terme peut aller et donne une bonne image de ce qu'il veut dire ?

Comment: Bien sûr Vous le savez, mais pas forcément Luc M ou tout autre lecteur non informaticien. S'ils retiennent votre proposition pour traduire *trim* au sujet du traitement d'une chaîne (bien défini dans la question),  ils seront incompréhensibles. A chaque domaine de l'informatique son jargon, ses choix, ses contraintes

Comment: Luc M dit dans sa question "Pour les non-initiés, etc". J'imaginais que s'il disait ça c'est qu'il connaissait. Mais c'est vrai que, dans le milieu informatique... Mais j'ai jamais vu un supporter de foot dire _Mais tiens tiens, quelle peut être la traduction de la fonction informatique trim() ?_ Et quand aux non informaticiens, traduire par détourer, je ne vois pas où est le mal ?

Answer (score 3):

Selon ces documents à moitié traduits, on pourrait utiliser `retirer()` ou `supprimer_des_espaces()`:

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php

> ltrim() - Supprime les espaces (ou d'autres caractères) de début de chaîne
>   rtrim() - Supprime les espaces (ou d'autres caractères) de fin de chaîne

http://www.afpy.org/doc/python/2.7/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-to-perl-s-chomp-for-removing-trailing-newlines-from-strings

> Si vous voulez retirer tous les espaces de fin de ligne, utilisez la
>   méthode rstrip() des chaines de caractères. Cela retire tous les
>   espaces de fin de ligne, pas seulement le caractère de fin de ligne.

Answer (score 2):

- `trim()`, par défaut enlève les espaces en début et en fin de chaîne, si elles existent
- `trim(caractèreASupprimer)` fait de même pour le caractère spécifié.
- plusieurs formules dont `l[eft]trim` et `r[ight]trim` permettent d'effectuer cette opération à une seule extrémité de la chaîne de caractères.

Il semble que le *trim* utilisé en informatique soit un raccourci de *trim off*, **enlever** traduction académique du ['Reverso'](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/trim/forced).

**EDIT** *Ajout des exemples*

> *Trim* (informatique) : Action d'enlever les espaces ou les caractères spécifiés éventuellement situés aux extrémités d'une chaîne de
>   caractères.
>   Ex. : La chaîne `--aBc-Ez-` sera transformée après une opération *trim()* sur le caractère `-` en `aBc-Ez`.
> **Compacter** une chaîne ; ne pas confondre avec
>   l'action de *compresser* qui consiste à réduire la taille de la chaîne.
>   Ex. : "Nous utiliserons dans la suite de cette documentation *compacter une chaine* (et les variantes possibles telles *compacter à gauche, à droite, le caractère*) pour traduire le mot *trim*."

**EDIT** *2*

> **Nettoyer** une chaîne pourrait aussi remplacer *compacter*, dans le sens où on n'enlève rien à l'objet *nettoyé* seulement ce qui a été ajouté, sans
>   le modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Sauf dans un contexte où la chasse aux emprunts à l'anglais est de règle, j'aurais tendance à garder `trim`

- il n'y a pas de terme qui s'est déjà imposé ;
- les emprunts sont une des manières qui font évoluer la langue, et une langue qui n'évolue pas est une langue morte ;
- le terme va être compris sans problème par une bonne partie des personnes intéressées ;
- aucun terme existant ne me semble être dans ce cas, sans définition, au mieux on va deviner juste et certaines propositions ont même des connotations qui peuvent mener au contre-sens (c'est particulièrement vrai pour *tronquer* qui a déjà un sens technique, mais *rogner* par exemple évoque plus pour moi une fonction qui ne regarderait pas ce qui est supprimé, *détourer* me semble plus adapté à du traitement d'images et face à *élaguer*, qui est à mon avis la meilleure proposition, je vais vérifier si la chaine ne doit pas représenter un arbre — oui, je manipule beaucoup d'arbres et de graphes)
- je ne trouve pas un néologisme plaisant ;
- pas de phonème inexistant en français dans ce mot.

L'inconvénient majeur est que [*trimer*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/trimer) existe déjà.  Inconvénient adouci par le fait que les acceptions existantes ne sont pas source de confusion et que le verbe y soit intransitif.

Answer (score 2):

*Trim* se traduit en français par cisaillement d'après le dictionnaire UltraLingua.

Comment: ça ne semble pas trop correspondre au sens informatique, car cisailler serait plutôt : couper en plusieurs petit morceaux, et pas vraiment couper aux extrémités.

Answer (score 1):

trim --> "ajuster" : rendre à sa taille raisonable / exploitable.